# ¿Como establecer el comando de un botón mediante un ciclo if en Tkinter Python 3.5?

Tags: python, tkinter

Este es mi problema, vengo comenzando a hacer mis aplicación con `Tkinter` y aun soy novato. Declaré unos cuantos `checkbuttons` con unos cuantos lenguajes y una `listbox` donde se almacenarán los lenguajes al hacer clic en el botón agregar.

Ahora lo que hice es un botón que al darle clic me agregue 3 `radiobuttons` y un botón normal a la ventana ya creada. El botón ejecuta la función reset.

```
def reset():
    opcion = IntVar()
    radioSel1 = Radiobutton(ventana, text="Reiniciar lenguajes", variable = 
    opcion, value = 1).place(x=15,y=280)

    radioSel2 = Radiobutton(ventana, text="Reiniciar lista", variable = 
    opcion, value = 2).place(x=15,y=300)

    radioSel3 = Radiobutton(ventana, text="Reiniciar todo", variable = 
    opcion, value = 3).place(x=15,y=320)   

    botonOk = Button(ventana, text="OK").place(x=15,y=350)

    if opcion == 1:
        botonOk.command(comOk1())
    elif opcion == 2:
        botonOk.config(command=comOk2())
    elif opcion == 3:
        botonOk.config(command=comOk3())
```

Lo que quiero es que el usuario decida qué hacer y seleccione un `radiobutton` y una vez decido que haga clic en el botón ok (que debería cumplir el comando elegido). Entonces declare el `if` y cambie el comando del botón desde ahí.

Esto es lo que debería ejecutar cada comando dependiendo de lo seleccionado en el `radiobutton`:

```
def comOk1():
    python.set(0)
    php.set(0)
    ruby.set(0)
    c.set(0)
    cc.set(0)

def comOk2():
    listLenguajes.delete(0,END)

def comOk3():
    python.set(0)
    php.set(0)
    ruby.set(0)
    c.set(0)
    cc.set(0)
    listLenguajes.delete(0,END)
```

Cuando ejecuto la aplicación no me da ningún error, pero al presionar ok no sucede nada. He probado de muchas maneras pero el resultado es el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema de lógica. Cuando ejecutas al función `reset` creas los `radiobuttons` e inmediatamente comprubas el valor de `opcion`. Al usuario no le ha dado tiempo de seleccionar nada y ese `if` no se ejecuta más por lo que nunca le asignas una función al botón.

La solución es definir una función para el `botonOk` y dentro leer el la variable y actuar en consecuencia. La variable `opcion` ha de ser definida dentro del ambito de `ventana` y no dentro de la fución, si se hace esto dejará de existir cuando se complete la ejecucuión de `reset` por lo que será inútil.

```
opcion = IntVar()

def comOk():
    op = opcion.get()
    if op == 1:
        python.set(0)
        php.set(0)
        ruby.set(0)
        c.set(0)
        cc.set(0)
    elif op == 2:
        listLenguajes.delete(0,END)
    elif op == 3:
        python.set(0)
        php.set(0)
        ruby.set(0)
        c.set(0)
        cc.set(0)
        listLenguajes.delete(0,END)

def reset():
    radioSel1 = Radiobutton(ventana, text="Reiniciar lenguajes", variable = opcion, value = 1)
    radioSel1.place(x=15,y=280)

    radioSel2 = Radiobutton(ventana, text="Reiniciar lista", variable = opcion, value = 2)
    radioSel2.place(x=15,y=300)

    radioSel3 = Radiobutton(ventana, text="Reiniciar todo", variable = opcion, value = 3)
    radioSel3.place(x=15,y=320)   

    botonOk = Button(ventana, text="OK", command  =comOk)
    botonOk.place(x=15,y=350)
```

Dos observaciones:

- Si usas el método `place`, `pack` o `grid` en la misma declaración del widget:

  ```
  botonOk = Button(ventana, text="OK").place(x=15,y=350)
  ```

  La variable `botonOk` ahora no es un botón, es simplemente `None`, que es el retorno de `place`. Esto implica que despuén no puedes usar la variable `botonOk` para acceder al botón y a sus atributos. Es decir, `botonOk.config`, por ejemplo, dará error. Si vas a querer acceder al widget posteriormente debes separar su instancia de la aplicación del método `place`, `grid`, `pack`, etc:

  ```
  botonOk = Button(ventana, text="OK")
  botonOk.place(x=15,y=350)
  ```
- Por otro lado, no pones la forma en la que importas pero es muy común en Tkinter (por usar ejemplos y documentación no actualizados) usar `from tkinter import*`. En Python usar el método `from módulo import *` **es una mala práctica** al igual que `using namespace std;` en c++. En programas pequeños o importando módulos simples no debe haber problemas, pero con módulos complejos como NumPy, SciPy, Pandas, etc puedes encontrarte con errores importantes y difíciles de encontrar, generalmente por sobreescribir algun método sin darte cuenta.

  En su lugar se debe importar usando alguna de estas formas:

  -`from tkinter import Button, Radiobutton, IntVar`...
  -`import tkinter`
  -`import tkinter as tk`

  Una de las formas más comunes y cómodas es la última, en este caso cuando instancias un widget o usas cualquier cosa de Tkinter siempre especificas el espacio de nombres a usar (zen de python: 'explícito es mejor que implícito') evitando posibles problemas y haciendo el código mucho más legible por terceros:

  ```
   import tkinter as tk

   ventana = tk.Tk()

   opcion = tk.IntVar()
   radioSel1 = tk.Radiobutton(ventana, text="Reiniciar lenguajes", variable = 
   opcion, value = 1)
   radioSel1.place(x=15,y=280)  

   botonOk = tk.Button(ventana, text="OK")
   botonOk.place(x=15,y=350)

   ventana.mainloop()
  ```